# Jquery load() get a variable from another page

Tags: php, jquery

On my main page I have a content box where I load the content using Jquery's load() from another page. All is working fine and it's quick and nice.
Next thing I want to do is to add a small filtering feature to it. The variable is sent to the main page (snappage.php) as a GET variable. However the php for the sql query is in another page (i.e all-snaps.php). Let me show you my code:

snappage.php

```
    <?php  
      require "database/database.php";
      session_start();
       if($_GET['country']) {
          $country = $_GET['country'];
       } 
    ?>
<section class="main-snap-page-wrapper">
        <nav class="all-snaps-countries">
            <h4>Filter by country</h4>
            <ul>
                <?php
                    //GET COUNTRY FLAGS
                    $flagsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM countries");

                    while($getflag = mysql_fetch_array($flagsql)) {
                        $countryname = $getflag['countryname'];
                        $flag = $getflag['countryflag'];  ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="snappage.php?country=<?php echo $countryname?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $flag?>" alt="">
                        <h5><?php echo $countryname?></h5>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php  } ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="all-snaps-page">
            <nav class="main-page-tabs-wrapper">
                <ul class="main-page-tabs" id="<?php echo $country?>">
                    <li class="active-tab"><a href="all-snaps">All</a></li>
                    <li><a href="female-snaps">Female</a></li>
                    <li><a href="male-snaps">Male</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="main-snaps-content"></div>
            </nav>
      </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.main-snaps-content').load('all-snaps.php');

    $('.main-page-tabs li').on('click', function () {
        $('.main-page-tabs li').removeClass('active-tab');
        $(this).addClass('active-tab');

        var page = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        $('.main-snaps-content').load(page + '.php');
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Next is the page which I load into .main-snaps-content from i.e all-snaps.php:

all-snaps.php

```
<?php
require "database/database.php";
session_start();

if($_GET['country']) {
    $country = $_GET['country'];
    $newsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users JOIN fashionsnaps ON users.id = fashionsnaps.userid WHERE country = '$country' ORDER BY snapid ASC");
}
else {
    $newsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fashionsnaps ORDER BY snapid ASC");
}
?>
<ul class="snaps-display">
<?php 
    //GET SNAPS BY ID
    while ($getnew = mysql_fetch_array($newsql)) {

       $newsnappics = $getnew['snappic']; 
       $newsnapid = $getnew['snapid']; 
       ?>
     <li>
         <a href="snap.php?id=<?php echo $newsnapid?>">
              <img src="<?php echo $newsnappics?>" alt="">
         </a>
     </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

So what I want to achieve here is to load the filtered content from all-snaps.php into the .main-snaps-content which is on snappage.php.

Where should I send this $country variable? On which page should I retrieve it?

Comment: Please note that `mysql_*` is now deprecated as of `PHP7` because of security issues. It is suggested that you switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extensions.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, I'm using this on my PC only for testing. Will keep this in mind once I go live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with jQuery `load`.

In snappage.php:

```
$(".main-snaps-content").load("all-snaps.php?" + $.param({country: "<?php echo htmlentities($country); ?>"}));
```

**Update:**

You'll need better handling of the PHP `GET/$country` var. You can initialize it at the top of snappage.php like this:

```
$country = (isset($_GET['country'])) ? $_GET['country'] : '';
```

Then, your JS will need a conditional:

```
var country = "<?php echo htmlentities($country); ?>";
if (country) {
    $(".main-snaps-content").load("all-snaps.php?" + $.param({country: country}));
} else {
    $(".main-snaps-content").load("all-snaps.php");
}
```

Comment: Hey Bitwise, sorry for a belated reply. Thanks, it's working fine now!

Comment: No problem! And, great! :)